# How to display firebase data as list in html using javascript?

Tags: javascript, firebase

What I'm trying to do:

- I'm trying to build a comments system for a larger app in firebase.
- Right now all I'm trying to do is display strings submitted on the page as a list.
- I adapted this from a Livelinks tutorial on packt publishing, that allowed submitting of links/title, that are then displayed as a list.
- I removed the links part, and tried to adapt the title part for comments.

What's happening:

- Submitting the data works fine.
- The problem is displaying the data.
- The page will display a blank list.
- It knows the number of entries but not the actual values.

Questions

- My understanding of how it all works is limited, so I can't describe exactly how I am attempting to implement the specification
- I think the javascript creates an array, puts the firebase data in the array, then displays the array?
- I think I might be lacking a reference to the Firebase key/id, but I'm not sure how to do/where to put this.
- Every idea/avenue I've explored as a fix just seems to break things entirely.
- How do I get the firebase data using javascript, then display it as a list?

(Firebase reference has been changed to 'fbname' in code below).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```css
function Comments(fbname) {

  var firebase = new Firebase("https://" + fbname + ".firebaseio.com/");
  this.firebase = firebase;
  var commentsRef = firebase.child('comments');

  this.submitComment = function(text) {
    commentsRef.push({
    text: text
    });
  };

  this.onCommentsChanged = function() {};

 commentsRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
    var comments = snapshot.val();
    var preparedComments = [];
 
    for (var text in comments) {
      if (comments.hasOwnProperty(text)) {
        preparedComments.push({
          text: comments.text
        })
      }
    }
    this.onCommentsChanged(preparedComments);
  }.bind(this));
 
};

$(document).ready(function() {

 var ll = new Comments('fbname');

 $(".comment-form form").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    ll.submitComment($(this).find('input.comment-text').val());
    $(this).find("input[type=text]").val("").blur();
    return false;
  });

  ll.onCommentsChanged = function(comments) {
    $(".comments-list").empty();
    comments.map(function(comment) {
      var commentElement = "<li><a href='" + comments.text + "</a></li>";
      $(".comments-list").append(commentElement);
    });
  };

});
```

```html
<html>

  <head>
    <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.7/firebase.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Comments Test</h1>

    <div class="comment-form">
      <form>
        <input type="text" class="comment-text" placeholder="comment text.."/>
        <input type="submit" value="Comment"/>
      </form>
    </div>

    <div class="comments">
      <ul class="comments-list">
      </ul>
    </div>


  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: try my repo code which will help you https://github.com/uzaif313/firebase-angular i build with angularjs

Comment: If you want to access property when key is in variable you should use bracket notation `preparedComments.push({text: comments[text]})`

Comment: jcubic Can you clarify what you mean by this? Making this change alone has makes no difference.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This code might help:

```
db.collection("comments").get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
    querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
        // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
        var string = JSON.stringify(doc.data())
        var parsed = JSON.parse(string)
        document.getElementById("yourcontainer").innerHTML += parsed.text + 
        '<br>'
    });
});
```